# Spring JPA hibernate Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection

Still trying to get a feel for how everything in Spring comes together and I've hit another wall.

Application.java

```html
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {QuestionRepository.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```html
@Controller
public class TestController {
 
 @Autowired
 public QuestionRepository questionRepository;
 
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

QuestionRepository.java

```html
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Long>{

 //findBy methhods are special with spring/jpa 
 public Collection<Question> findByName(String title);
 
 public long count();
 
}
```

Question.java

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="questions")
public class Question {
 
 @Column(name="questionText")
 private String questionText;
 
 @Column(name="answerText")
 private String answerText;
 
 @Column(name="owningDeck")
 private String owningDeck;
 
 @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int id;
 
 
 public Question() {
 }
 
 
 public void setQuestion(String q, int id) {
  this.questionText = q;
 }
 
 
}
```

annnd The error trace showing failed injection

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public repo.QuestionRepository hello.TestController.questionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'questionRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#59f4e49e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#59f4e49e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:609)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:806)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:795)
 at hello.Application.main(Application.java:36)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public repo.QuestionRepository hello.TestController.questionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'questionRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#59f4e49e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#59f4e49e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'questionRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#59f4e49e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#59f4e49e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
 ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#59f4e49e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:442)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
 ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
 ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Any idea why I am not able to Autowire the QuestionRepository from my controller?

----Editing in application.properties file-----

application.properties

```html
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jpa.database=MYSQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception you are getting is in relation to how the Persistence Provider (or Database) is setup. Did you create a persistence.xml file and include all of your database settings in there?

One other small correction to your code which won't solve your problem posted here, but you've specified the Question class to have an id as follows:

```
private int id;
```

You'll need to update this to:

```
private Long id;
```

as you specified in your QuestionRepository class that the Key or Id field is of type Long.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I do not have a persistence.xml file in the project. I could look through some examples and see if I can find one that would get this to run correctly. I was worried that using xml files might override some of the autoconfigurations that spring provides and cause me more confusion but I have a feeling this may be the wrong way to think about it. I do see I forgot to add my application.properties file in the question and just edited that one in as it sets some db properties.

Comment: If you're worried about having xml files in your project, you can configure Spring to load the Presistence Provider using Java Configurations. In your case you would specifiy the EntityManger Bean that your code is complaining about. What Database are you trying to use for you application? Also, what Persistence Provider do you want to use? The answer to these question will help narrow down what you need to specify in your Configurations class.

Comment: I ended up just starting a separate project using another as a template and it worked. Eventually I'll probably look into getting down to why the previous code didn't work but for now just to be up and running is enough. Thanks and sorry to cut out like it.